# How to redirect through htaccess without changing the URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the code below to point all subdomains to their document root.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.co/%1/$1 [P]
```

`subdomain.example.co` will point to `example.co/subdomain` but the URL will remain untouched.

The problem with this is that when you try to retrieve the URL, through PHP, it will always return `example.co/subdomain` despite the fact that the URL bar displays it as a subdomain. I believe this is due to the Proxy flag.

How could I achieve the same effect but allow for the actual URL that the user is on (the subdomain) to be retrieved?

**Overall**

- allsubdomains.example.co should point to example.co/allsubdomains
- The URL should remain as allsubdomains.example.co
- When retrieving the current URL through PHP, it should return allsubdomains.example.co

Comment: _"I believe this is due to the Proxy flag."_ - yes, of course. Instead of making the client request `http://example.co/subdomain/foo`, you made Apache do it. So Apache becomes the client in a new request, and the server of course sees `http://example.co/subdomain/foo` as the request URL - because _that is what happened_. Assuming this all happens on the same server, you do not want to proxy the request at all, you just want to rewrite it _internally_; sth. like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1`

Comment: @CBroe Hey, thanks for the response! For some reason, I'm just pointed to an error page when using the rewrite rule rather than `sub.example.co` pointing to `example.co/sub` with the same URL

Comment: Likely due to an endless redirect. Since you are now rewriting internally, the host name does not change when the next round starts. So you might need to add another condition to check if the path already begins with one of your subdomain names. And if that is not possible, because there are too many, then you will have to find another way to detect that.

Comment: @CBroe I have just tested this out using http://htaccess.mwl.be/. I think it now returns an error because it's not pointed to anything. The only redirects I have is http to https (along with this current one which doesn't work)

Comment: @CBroe Looks like it points to `subdomain.example.co/subdomain` rather than `example.co/subdomain`